# Understanding Textmate help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, textmate

I am trying to become familiar with Textmate shortcut keys.
However when I open my "Demo Help" for the Ruby on Rails Bundle it shows keymappings with characters like "& # x21E5"

When I paste them in here they often display correctly as they appear to be HTML escape codes but in the Textmate window they are unreadable. I cant keep referring to a list of HTML escape codes!

How am I supposed to translate those key mappings. Have I got something set up wrongly that they show like this rather than with the normal symbols?

Cheers
George

Answer (score 1):

⇥ appears to be a "normal" key symbol, meaning tab (forward tab, specifically). A quick googling led me to [this page](http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2005/05/special-key-symbols.html), which seems to have a number of such mappings. For reference, the phrase I googled was "key symbols mac".

Using symbols not on the key to represent a key is fairly common when describing mac shortcuts, you have probably not done anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the help file is showing you the unicode hex symbol instead of the actual glyph in the font. If you have Unicode text enabled, inside TextMate you can hold down the Option key and type the four digit code to get a quick translation. Kind of a pain while you're reading a help file but they probably only use a few.

From the Ruby on Rails Bundle Help the ones I see (my version is also showing the codes not the glyphs) are:
2303 is the Control Key
2318 is the Command Key
2325 the option key
21e5 is the Tab key
232b is Delete
2193 Down arrow
21e7 up arrow
21a9 return

BTW, You enter unicode here in SO by entereing &# followed by the decimal code and then  a semi-colon,  So x21e5 is 8677 decimal so &#8677; yields  ⇥